# Need collapsible pane for all uls in the following navigation code. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am working on making a dynamic populated menu a collapsible menu. I have a large list to display which populates with some descriptive section headings in the middle. I have tried using the collapsible menu but I have no luck. Please look at the menu I have as an HTML code and please help me make it collapsible:

```html
<div class="card flex-fill w-100">
  <div class="card-header">
    Carriers And Documents
  </div>

  <div class="card-body py-3" style="margin-top:8px;">

    <div class="col-md-12 row ">
      <div class="col-md-5 accordian" id="carrierResults">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Registered Carriers @{ foreach (var carrier in Model.RegisteredCarriers) {
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
              <li class="sidebar-header">
                <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
                <a class="LinkedObjects" asp-controller="RegisteredCarriersAndDocuments" asp-action="GetCarrier" asp-route-GUID="@carrier.GuID" id='"@carrier.GuID"'>
                                                        @carrier.DisplayName
                                                    </a>
                <ul class="sidebar-header">
                  <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Services
                    <ul class="Last-Indent">
                      @{ foreach (var service in carrier.Services) {
                      <li class="sidebar-item">
                        <a class="LinkedObjects" asp-controller="RegisteredCarriersAndDocuments" asp-action="GetService" asp-route-Symbol="@service.Symbol" asp-route-CarrierSymbol="@carrier.Symbol">
                                                                                @service.DisplayName
                                                                            </a>
                      </li>
                      } }
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Documents
                    <ul class="Last-Indent">
                      @{ foreach (var document in carrier.Documents) {
                      <li class="sidebar-header">
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
                        <a class="LinkedObjects" asp-controller="RegisteredCarriersAndDocuments" asp-action="GetCarrierDocumentDetail" asp-route-CarrierSymbol="@carrier.Symbol" asp-route-DocumentSymbol="@document.Symbol">
                                                                                @document.DisplayName
                                                                            </a>
                        <ul class="sidebar-header">
                          <li>
                            <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Output Options
                            <ul class="Last-Indent">
                              @{ foreach (var option in document.Options) {
                              <li class="sidebar-item">
                                <a class="LinkedObjects" asp-controller="RegisteredCarriersAndDocuments" asp-action="GetCarrierDocumentOption" asp-route-option="@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@option)">
                                                                                                        @option.Stock.ToString() , @option.Output.ToString()
                                                                                                    </a>
                              </li>
                              } }
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      } }
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            } }
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul style="list-style: none;">
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Registered Documents @{ foreach (var document in Model.RegisteredDocs) {
            <ul class="sidebar-nav" style="list-style: none;">
              <li class="sidebar-header">
                <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
                <a class="LinkedObjects" asp-controller="RegisteredCarriersAndDocuments" asp-action="GetDocument" asp-route-GUID="@document.GuID">
                                                        @document.DisplayName
                                                    </a>
                <ul class="sidebar-header" style="list-style: none;">
                  <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Output Options
                    <ul class="Last-Indent" style="list-style: none;">
                      @{ foreach (var option in document.Options) {
                      <li class="sidebar-item">
                        <a class="LinkedObjects" asp-controller="RegisteredCarriersAndDocuments" asp-action="GetDocumentsOption" asp-route-option="@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@option)">
                                                                                @option.Stock.ToString() , @option.Output.ToString()
                                                                            </a>
                      </li>
                      } }
                    </ul>
                  </li>

                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            } }
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="dispalyRelatedContent" class="col-md-7">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is proving to be a big challenge for me right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to implement a Bootstrap accordion. First, the class you have in the outer div is misspelled, it should be `accordion`.

Second, you haven't used any of the `collapse` classes, `data-toggle`, or `data-target` attributes you would need to make the menu actually collapse.

[Check out the Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/) for how to implement this.